# html forms with its model not submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have three buttons and three forms into their divs(Models) at one page. All divs(Models) with their forms are hidden.  First time when page is loaded. One div with its ID and its form is cloned and shown into another div#`replace section`. Then When I try to submit it. its not submitted the form. why? see code here

here all div(Models) with its form is replace when click on button

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="text-center margin-top10 fsize60"></h1>
  <section class="text-center replace-section">
    <!-- forms are shown here when button is click  -->
  </section>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#frm_infradi_result").click().clone().removeClass('hide').addClass('show').prependTo(".replace-section");

      $("button[name='btn_infradi_result']").click(function() {
        $('.replace-section').empty();
        $("#frm_infradi_result").click().clone().removeClass('hide').addClass('show').prependTo(".replace-section");
      });

      $("button[name='btn_madaris_result']").click(function() {
        $('.replace-section').empty();
        $("#frm_madaris_result").click().clone().removeClass('hide').addClass('show').prependTo(".replace-section");
      });

      $("button[name='btn_hifz_result']").click(function() {
        $('.replace-section').empty();
        $("#frm_hifz_result").click().clone().removeClass('hide').addClass('show').prependTo(".replace-section");
      });

      $("button[name='btn_nazer_sani']").on('click', function() {
        $('#modal_nazer_sani').show();
      });

    });
```

---

```
<!-- 1 div#frm_infradi_result with its form -->

<div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-3 animated fadeInRight animation-delay-5 hide" id="frm_infradi_result">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h3 class="h2 ur no-margin-padding" style="display: inline;">
                انفرادى مکتب نتائج برائے سال 1437ھ
            </h3>
      <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <form method="post" id="frm_result" action="mailto:itsoftsaeed@gmail.com">
            <!-- here is form elements list -->
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- 2 div#frm_madaris_result with its form -->

  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-3 animated fadeInRight animation-delay-5 hide" id="frm_madaris_result">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h3 class="h2 ur no-margin-padding" style="display: inline;">
                انفرادى مکتب نتائج برائے سال 1437ھ
            </h3>
        <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form method="post" id="frm_madaris" action="mailto:itsoftsaeed@gmail.com">
              <!-- here is form elements list -->
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 3 div#frm_hifz_result with its form -->

    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-3 animated fadeInRight animation-delay-5 hide" id="frm_hifz_result">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
          <h3 class="h2 ur no-margin-padding" style="display: inline;">
                انفرادى مکتب نتائج برائے سال 1437ھ
            </h3>
          <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <form method="post" id="frm_hifz" action="mailto:itsoftsaeed@gmail.com">
                <!-- here is form elements list -->
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Because : duplicate IDs. Use classes, not ID. ID must be unique.

Comment: sorry, I can't understand what you are saying @Jeremy Thille, a bit explain it.

Comment: Well, you have a form with an ID, right : `<form id="frm_infradi_result">`. If you clone it, you will also clone its ID along with it, meaning you will have two HTML elements with the same ID, and that messes things up. ID must be unique. So, instead of IDs, use classes :  `<form class="frm_infradi_result">` and select them using `$(".frm_infradi_result")`

Comment: nice, to understand and quick reply thanks @JeremyThille Thille  let me try it

Comment: I convert all ID into classes and clone it. but not work :( @JeremyThille where is mistake ? i.e `<div id='frm_hifz_result'>` convert into ` <div class='frm_hifz_result'> `  div contain required form. and clone the div. everything ok but form not submit

Comment: Please try and make a fiddle, that will help understand what's wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can I give u teamviewer ID and check it ? @JeremyThille

Comment: Uh no, we don't do that on stackoverflow :) and I'm not free for that. People make a fiddle, so we can help debug the app.

Comment: thanks to your cooperate, the problem is solved now :) @JeremyThille

Comment: No problem mate, glad I could help.